# two different tables a part of the same entity

Tags: entity-relationship, openjpa

I have an entity which needs fields from another table.  The second table is basically an extension of the first as they have the same primary key...

For instance

```
Organization 1:             OrganizationExtension
___________                 _____________________
PK: OrgaID                   PK: OrgID
```

How can I get those two tables into the same entity bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here...
[OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.1.0/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_field.html#jpa_overview_mapping_secondary)

Essentially you would do this...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ART")
@SecondaryTable(name="ART_DATA", 
    pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ART_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
public class Article {

    @Id private long id;

    @Column(table="ART_DATA")
    private byte[] content;

    ...
}
```

if you were using Annotations and not XML... 
only question remaining would be how do you identify the columns in the second table?

Answered the second part of that as well...
You would just do the following `@Column(table="ORGANIZATION_LINK", name="EVENING_HOURS")`